# How to get timestamp of a remote country in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I want to get timestamp of a different country in VBA. Is there any direct function or way to get it? For example, I am in India working for Mexico and I want to do certain task based on Mexican Time. I was able to get it by splitting the timestamp and manipulating it but could not consider daylight saving in it. Is there any simple solution than writing a big user-defined function?

Comment: You might consider [The Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

Comment: Perhaps a medium-sized user-defined function?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks a lot. It worked. But it is not a permanent solution for me as I cannot ask the end users to keep changing the system clock.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I am sorry, I am new to VBA and have no idea how to use an API in VBA. Started looking for it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett That would be my probable solution if I cannot get any better solution from the experts here..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Know your time zone offset & your client's time zone offset, then use that to calculate the difference

```
Dim IndiaTZ as single  
Dim MexicoTZ as single
Dim MyTime as date
Dim UTC as date
Dim MexicoTime as date

IndiaTZ = 5.5
MexicoTZ = -4
'note this assumes that they're in Eastern time, 
'Mexico also covers Central, Mountain & Pacific at -5, -6 & -7. 
'You'll need to figure out which one you need.

MyTime = Now
'need to invert the offset to get from India to UTC
UTC = datediff("h", mytime, IndiaTZ * -1)
'need to invert the offset to get from UTC to Mexico
MexicoTime = Datediff("h", UTC, MexicoTZ * -1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As I mentioned in my question, I was able to get this done but the problem is with daylight saving. India does not have daylight saving whereas Mexico has.. I would have to change this code every 6 months once to change the offset difference.

Comment: You could look up the DST On and DST Off dates, then have the code adjust the offset based on the date. That way you don't have to update it, just let it run & tell the folks in MX to let you know if they change their DST dates.

Comment: Thanks for the leads. I got the solution in cpearson website. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx

Comment: Glad that helped, and thanks for posting that back, I've got that bookmarked now, myself!